# Bounding using Kantorovich inequality

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, upper-lower-bounds

In my homework, I've made it to the point where I obtained this value

$$\frac{(v^Tv)^2}{v^TQvv^TQ^{-1}v}$$

where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $Q$ is symmetric positive definite.

I know I have to use Kantorovich's inequality:

> For $v_1, \ldots, v_n >0 \ : \ v_1 \leq v_2 \leq \ldots \leq v_n$ and $w_1, ... w_n \geq 0 \ : \ w_1 + w_2 + \cdots w_n=1$, then,
>   $$(\sum  w_i v_i)(\sum w_i v_i^{-1}) \leq \frac{(v_1+v_n)^2}{4v_1v_n}$$

I am confused with how to proceed though. I know one of either $v$'s or $w$'s is the elements of the sum $v^Tv$. My main problem is finding what is $w_i$ and $v_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q=U^TD U$ be the symmetric eigenvalue decomposition with sorted eigenvalues. Let $r=Uv$,

\begin{align}
\frac{(v^Tv)^2}{v^TQvv^TQ^{-1}v} &= \frac{(v^Tv)^2}{v^TU^TD Uvv^TU^TD^{-1} Uv} \\
&=\frac{(r^Tr)^2}{r^TD rr^TD^{-1} r} \\
&= \frac{(r^Tr)^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^nd_ir_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nd_i^{-1}r_i^2\right)}
\end{align}

Hopefully you can take it from here.